# UIDatePicker for iOS13 and above and below iOS13

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, ios12

Implemented UIDatePicker for iOS14 supported but needs support for iOS 12 as well. How to implement the same for iOS12 as well. Below is my code:

```
datePicker = UIDatePicker.init()
        datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
        datePicker.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        
    }
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Error in iOS12:

```
preferredDatePickerStyle' is only available in iOS 13.4 or newer
```

What to implement under check below iOS 13?

Comment: No need to specify below iOS 13 it will take the default wheel style picker.

Comment: @RajaKishan no, it's throwing error "preferredDatePickerStyle' is only available in iOS 13.4 or newer"

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to specify anything for `< iOS 13.4` versions. `UIDatePicker` will work as it used to in older versions without specifying this value.

If you want to FORCE old `iOS 12` style on the new devices `iOS 14 or above` as well, you can use -

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```

Comment: There's no way you can get a behavior on iOS 12 that's only allowed iOS 13.4 or later. You need to decide one of these two - a) Let the system show different behaviors according to iOS versions - in this you don't need to specify anything at all - this is driven by system automatically. OR b) Force the old iOS 12 behavior (wheels) on all phones for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for under iOS 13.4 you don't have another option to choose. You can only use UIDatePicker with .wheels style.

In order to choose a style, you must have a version of at least iOS 13.4. (iOS 14.0 for .inline style)

You can use .wheels for lower versions. But you might have to redesign your UI.

On the other hand, you can use third-party date components or create your own date component to provide consistency between versions.

Answer (score -2):

Under the `iOS 13` you can use automatic.

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .automatic
    }
```

Comment: same error: preferredDatePickerStyle' is only available in iOS 13.4 or newer

Comment: `preferredDatePickerStyle` is available from iOS 13.4 onwards.